# Remove rows from data table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I am trying to clean different data frames based on conditions.

This is what I have

**df1**

```
| Muertes  | Unnamed 1 | Unnamed 2 | 
|----------|-----------|---------- |
|State     |  County   | Number    | 
|Ags       |   Llano   |   5       |
|Cali      |  P.Alto   |   8       |
|Morelia   |   Lagos   |   6       |
```

**df2**

```
|  Ags     | Llano     |   5       | 
|----------|-----------|---------- |
|  Cali    |  P.Alto   |   8       | 
|Morelia   |  Lagos    |   9       |
|          |           |   8       |
|          |           |   6       |
```

For the **df1** I want to remove the first row "Muertes, Unnamed 1 and Unnamed 2" I tried to do this part with these code lines

```
#listdf = list of my data frames

listdf[1].drop(["Muertes"], inplace = True) 
>> "['Muertes'] not found in axis"
```

1. This was my first mistake, then I tried to use the second row (State, County and Number) as the header of my columns after removing the row "Muertes".
2. Then I want to append in vertical way the df2 to the df1 I tried with the function append but my result is not what I expected

**Result expected**

```
| State    | County    |    Number | 
|----------|-----------|---------- |
|Ags       |   Llano   |   5       |
|Cali      |  P.Alto   |   8       |
|Morelia   |   Lagos   |   6       |
|Cali      |  P.Alto   |   8       |
|Morelia   |   Lagos   |   6       |
```

Thanks for your attention and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df1:

```
    Model1  Model2  Model3
0   State   Age     Number
1   86      96      56
2   23      98      23
```

df2:

```
    A   B   C
0   86  96  56
1   23  98  23
```

Column Names adjustment:

```
df1.columns = df1.iloc[0]
df1 = df1[1:]
```

Rename columns for df2:

```
df2 = df2.rename(columns={"A": "State", "B": "Age", "C":"Number"})
```

Concat df1 and df2

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
new_df
```

Output:

```
   State    Age  Number
1     86    96   56
2     23    98   23
3     23    98   23
4     32    34   44
```